# Odd Files Operations Progress Bar

Tags: 20.04, nautilus, files

I am currently backing up a large amount of files.

The progress bar reads: 3,143/1,1196

Anyone know what that means?

Also the first number keeps rising.

**Note:** I have started and stopped the copying action, also I have chosen to merge folders and skip existing files. Files version is 3.36.3-stable.

[Files Operation Progress Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/953F4.png)

Answer (score 0):

The meaning simply is

```
X units of a total of Y units have been processed
```

So

> The progress bar reads: 3,143/1,1196

means that currently there have been processed 3143 units of a total of 11196 units.